# False preacher get converted by a real miracle 80's or 90's

Tags: identify-this-movie

This movie is about a false preacher that has a show where he make miracles. All those miracles are somehow arranged to fool believers. There's a man who thinks the preacher is a fake just to make money from people. This man is a cop or inspector (he doesn't dress a police uniform)

Main actors are white. Black chorus singers working with the preacher.

There's a girl working with the false preacher who fall in love with the "cop" and they end together in the movie.

At the end of the movie, there's a boy asking for a miracle because he can't walk without crutches. The preacher speeds the ending to avoid being put in evidence that he has no power to heal the boy or anybody. But the boy got up to the stage and touched a statue of Jesus and got cured.

That night the preacher got onto a truck and went away leaving his team of thieves. In the way, it began to rain and the preacher started to sing praising the lord 'cause all the town was asking him for the rain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds a lot like 1992's [Leap Of Faith](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104695/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_29), staring Steve Martin.
From the description on IMDB:

> Jonas is a fraudulent faith healer, who uses all the tricks in the book to con the people attending his shows. Jonas and his team of helpers, including Jane who is in need of some romance, travel the country stopping at big towns and cities to put on their show. When one of the trucks breaks down in a small town, Jonas is quick to accept the challenge of making money in this town. His other goal is to seduce Marva, a waitress in the town, but she's a hard nut to crack, as is Will, the local sheriff who's determined to expose Jonas as a fraud.

Comment: Yes! Steve Martin ! that's the preacher. Liam Neeson is also there.. how I  couldn't remember that. Thanks a lot for the quick answer.